# Exported filter with preloaded value

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I defined a profile field for users called "Size" which can take the values "Small", "Normal" and "Big", so it's presented as a combo box.
Now I have a Page view with an exposed filter defined over "Size", furthermore the filter is optional so an "Any" value is presented in the combo box.

Two questions:

1. When the user enters the view page the result list is automatically showed. Can I wait for the user to click "Search" to display the results?
2. Can I pre-select the value in the combo box with the value stored for that user in that profile field?, i.e. if the user's value for "Size" is "Big", can I pre-select "Big" in the combo box of the view search page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you cannot. Without to write custom code, it's not possible.
2. No, you cannot. It would not make sense, anyway, as a view is thought to show the content of possibly multiple elements (user profiles, in this case). Which value should the filter show? The value of the first user profile shown?

It is possible to make a filter show the last value a user selected. Supposing that user A selects `Big`, then all the times user A watches that view, he will see the user profiles for which the field `Size` contains the value `Big`. User A can obviously change the value of the filter all times he wants.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Regarding your answer to question 2, I forgot to say the view is only accessible to online users, so the filter value I'd like to pre-select is the profile value of the user who's performing the search.